# HTML and XML parsing Java

Tags: java, android, html, xml, parsing

I am starting to program an android application, that will be based on nutritiondata.com,

The problem is.. they have no API for developers, and it seems very hard and confusing to me, and I am not sure how to parse the information from the site to my app.

For example.. using their food search.. is something I understand, example of an avocado search:

http://nutritiondata.self.com/foods-avocado000000000000000000000.html

So here I can replace the /foods-.... other food name ... 00000000000.html

but once I go deeper inside the avocado detailed nutritionds, I have no idea how to pull specific data like the omega 3 and 6 content of the avocado in grams or the proteins, I tried using the "source page" to find usefull data but How the heck am I supposed to work with this data, representing the amount of omega 3 and 6 fats in the avocado.

```
       <div class="clearer">
       <div class="nf1 left" id="nfacts">


         <div class="indentation"><!--Indent Nutrients--></div>

<span class="indented">Total Omega-3 fatty acids</span></div>

        <div class="nf2 left" style="width:38px;"><span id="NUTRIENT_139"></span></div>
        <div class="nf3 left" style="width:20px;"><span id="UNIT_NUTRIENT_139"></span>    </div>
        <div class="nf4 left" style="width:31px;"><span id="DV_NUTRIENT_139"></span></div>
```

```
    <div class="clearer">
       <div class="nf1 left" id="nfacts">


         <div class="indentation"><!--Indent Nutrients--></div>

<span class="indented">Total Omega-6 fatty acids</span></div>

        <div class="nf2 left" style="width:38px;"><span id="NUTRIENT_140"></span></div>
        <div class="nf3 left" style="width:20px;"><span id="UNIT_NUTRIENT_140"></span></div>
        <div class="nf4 left" style="width:31px;"><span id="DV_NUTRIENT_140"></span></div>
```

I would really appreciate a working example of how to work with this type of data or the website, Thank you with all of my heart, for the time/afford and help.

Comment: The integration method you used is called 'screen scraping' and it's often considered as hacky unreliable techniques. If nutritiondata.com changes their website look & feel your code can easily break. Best to contact their site and ask for developer API / other integration approach. If you still want to go ahead there are few html normalization library such as tagsoup. Combined with XSL you can screen scrape various bits and pieces inside the page. At the very least if you decide to screen scrape its best to download offline copy of the entire site (provided it's legal to do so)

Comment: Try looking at their scripts - if they use templates + ajax, you can simply copy their requests.

Comment: check this https://code.google.com/p/java-wikipedia-parser/wiki/Introduction

Answer (score 0):

Try JSOUP for screen scraping http://jsoup.org/ but as others pointed out - it's not long term reliable technique.